# maintaining scroll position causes page to jump

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scroll

I'm developing a web site using asp.net 2.0 and I recently added a few lines of `javascript` to save the `scroll position` of a div `across postbacks`.
 The problem is that when the page loads the div's scroll position starts at the top and then jumps to the saved position.
 How do I get rid of this jump effect? The website is located at www.collectedlight.net.

Here's the javascript that I'm using to maintain scroll position:

```
window.onload = function () {
   //maintain the scroll position for the list of photos across postbacks
   var scrollPos = document.getElementById('ctl00_pagePlaceHolder_photoListScrollPos').value;
   document.getElementById('photoListScrollBar').scrollTop = scrollPos;
}

//save the scroll position of the list of photos
function SaveScrollPos() {
   var scrollPos = document.getElementById('photoListScrollBar').scrollTop;
   document.getElementById('ctl00_pagePlaceHolder_photoListScrollPos').value = scrollPos;
}
```

The scroll position DOES get saved but as the page is loading I can see the scroll position first set to the top and then jump down to the saved scroll position. I want the page to load at the saved scroll position without the jump effect. Is this possible?

Comment: you cant keep js variable after postback, there is some solution , try keep your js variable to cookie, or try using ajax update panel

Comment: Posting those few lines of javascript might help us get a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: I can't replicate the behaviour you describe in either Chrome or IE9. It's either not behaving as you describe, or happening so fast that I can't notice it. On that point, the speed of execution might be a factor? Do you have other script executing before that? Elements that might be delaying the "onload" event?

Answer (score 0):

By attaching your code to the `window.onload` event, you're preventing your code from running until all page assets (including images) have loaded. This is why you're only seeing the issue when one of the pictures takes a while to load. You can probably solve your issue by attaching to the `DOMContentLoaded` event instead. By attaching to this event at the bottom of your page, you ensure that your code executes once the DOM and CSS are loaded and your page layout is basically ready, without having to wait for every single page asset to be loaded. See here for more details: http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/06/14/how-javascript-loading-works-domcontentloaded-and-onload/.